# set up websocket on hostgator with shared hosting

Tags: html, websocket

I would like to try to use the HTML5 websockets API to create a video chat app.  I understand what to do on the client side, but I don't know how to set up the server side.  I am currently using shared hosting on hostgator, I am wondering if I can set up websockets on my server without upgrading to VPS hosting or a dedicated server.  Also, the server limits the number of processes running to 25, does this mean then that if I do set up a websocket, I can only have at most 25 users using the chat application.  If this is not possible, then I would like to know any cheap alternatives.

Comment: did you ever find a cheap alternative that allowed you to use HTML5 websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for web sockets you need to run an entire socket level server (like apache runs on port 80) that can speak the websocket protocol. ask hostgator if they would allow you to do so...

Answer (score 5):

From the [HostGator Support Portal](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/socket-connections):

> **Socket Connections**
>
> A socket is defined as one endpoint of a two-way communication link between two programs running on the network. A socket is bound to a port number so that the TCP layer can identify to which application the data is sent.
>
> You are not allowed to use or create new inbound socket connections.
>
> **PHP Socket Support?**
>
> If you are connecting out, it should work. We do not allow clients to bind to local ports for incoming.

Seems that you must use a dedicated server or VPS.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: What does it mean "in-bound" and "connecting out"? Is this referring to the initiator of the handshake, being either client (in-bound) or server (connecting out)?